# Mysql Replace function issue

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to update my table with replace function, but the result is not my expected result, how can I solve this problem?

Lets say I have a LONGTEXT columns(using_id) with value like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,

Now I want to remove '1,' so I write in this way:-

```
 Dim query As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET using_id = REPLACE(using_id,'" & $"{g_currTicketID}," & "','')"
```

But the result become 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1  How can I keep my '11,'?

Expected result: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,

[image]

```
Public Sub TicketStatusUpdate(p_str As String)
        'Login => GET NEXT ID > UPDATE USING ID > UPDATE NEXT ID
        'Sales => RELEASE > UPDATE USED ID > GET NEXT ID > UPDATE USING ID > UPDATE NEXT ID

        Select Case p_str
            Case "UPDATE USED ID"
                TicketStatusUpdate("RELEASE")

                Dim query As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET used_id = CONCAT(used_id, '" & $"{g_currTicketID}," & "')"
                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

                TicketStatusUpdate("GET NEXT ID")

            Case "GET NEXT ID"
                Dim query_select = "SELECT * FROM curr_id WHERE DATE(curr_date) = '" & Format(DateTime.Today.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' "
                Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
                Dim IsNewDay As Boolean = False

                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query_select, conn)
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    reader.Read()
                    If reader.HasRows Then
                        g_currTicketID = reader.GetInt32("next_id")
                    Else
                        g_currTicketID = 1
                        IsNewDay = True
                    End If
                    reader.Close()
                End Using

                If IsNewDay Then TicketStatusUpdate("RESET")
                TicketStatusUpdate("UPDATE USING ID")
                TicketStatusUpdate("UPDATE NEXT ID")

            Case "UPDATE USING ID"
                Dim query As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET using_id = CONCAT(using_id, '" & $"{g_currTicketID}," & "')"
                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

            Case "UPDATE NEXT ID"
                Dim query1 As String = "SELECT * FROM curr_id"
                Dim str_usingID As String = ""
                Dim str_usedID As String = ""

                Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query1, conn)
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    reader.Read()
                    str_usingID = reader.GetString("using_id").ToString
                    str_usedID = reader.GetString("used_id").ToString
                    reader.Close()
                End Using

                Dim str_allID As String = (str_usingID + str_usedID).TrimEnd(",")
                Dim strArray As String() = str_allID.Split(",")
                Dim intArray As Integer() = Array.ConvertAll(strArray, Function(s) Int32.Parse(s))
                Array.Sort(Of Integer)(intArray)

                Dim nextID As Integer = FirstMissing(intArray)

                Dim query2 As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET next_id = '" & nextID & "'"
                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query2, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

            Case "RELEASE"
                Dim query As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET using_id = REPLACE(using_id,'" & $"{g_currTicketID}," & "','')"
                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

            Case "RESET"
                Dim query As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET next_id='',used_id='',using_id=''"
                Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
        End Select
    End Sub

 Private Function FirstMissing(sequence() As Integer) As Integer
        Dim seq = sequence
        Dim firstMissingNumer = Int32.MinValue

        For i = 1 To Math.Min(seq.Last, seq.Count)
            If seq(i - 1) <> i Then
                firstMissingNumer = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If firstMissingNumer = Int32.MinValue Then
            Return seq.Max + 1
        Else
            Return firstMissingNumer
        End If
    End Function
```

When I logout the application it will call TicketStatusUpdate("RELEASE") to remove the g_currTicketID from using_id column.

Examples:

```
g_currTicketID = 1
using_id = 1,11,21,31,
```

When TicketStatusUpdate("RELEASE") called it will remove all '1,' from using_id, so the result will become 1,2,3 which is not the result that I want, I only want to remove '1,' and keep '11,21,31,'

Comment: Please check your values in debug mode of `g_currTicketID`

Comment: I think `replace` is not required

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam g_currTicketID is an integer, for example above it will be 1

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam If replace is not required which function should I use?

Comment: Please show your full code of function, also add tag of visual basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replace just value, you could try to replace both value and boundary character 
(in your case, comma ',' is a boundary character).
Example:

With g_currTicketID = 1, using_id = 1,11,21,31, then

```
replaceValue = CONCAT(',',g_currTicketID,',') = ',1,'
stringToReplace = CONCAT(',',using_id,',') = ',1,11,21,31,'
using_id = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(stringToReplace, replaceValue, ','))
```

Your updat statement could be like this

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE curr_id SET using_id = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',' ,using_id, ','), '," & $"{g_currTicketID}," & "', ','))"
```